# open on the same window form submit

Tags: php, ajax, printing, fpdf

```js
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
form.setAttribute("action", "target.php");


document.body.appendChild(form); // Not entirely sure if this is necessary           
form.submit();
return;
```

I have the above code inside the success of an ajax succes. On success of saving data in the database I send back the said data to be print. I am using FPDF for printing and I have create a template in `target.php` and I am posting data into that page. So in order to send the data through post I create a form with target set as `_blank` expecting that when I save another set of data the and print the said data it will open on the previous tab. What is happening now is every time I save data it opens new tab.

What I expect is every time I save and print the data it will open to the previous tab that was opened on first print. Basically I dont want to open new tab every time I print. On first print open new tab then the rest will just load on that tab

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use _self  instead of _blank.

Comment: i dont want it to open in current tab . **Basically I dont want to open new tab every time I print. On first print open new tab then the rest will just load on that tab**

Answer (score 0):

Is there such thing as **_black**

When I use this one I get the desired functionality I want

I tried a simple demo in `w3school` like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Open link in a new window or tab: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_black">Visit W3Schools!</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to know if this is a valid target